# No Safari Developer Certificate, Windows 7

Tags: safari, certificate, safari-extensions

I've added safari developer certificate to 'Personal' and 'Trusted Root Certification Authority' but extension builder still shows:

> No Safari Developer Certificate

I'm using windows 7. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to export .p12 (private key) file from Mac and run it on Windows machine. It should work now.